Merging multiple folders and cataloging content and duplicate file information
I am having to cleanup a mess some one made and I'm in the situation of I don't know what I don't know.  I need a way to merge 3 sets of data on a new server and remove duplicates by name/content.
The backstory is due to previous management of the data 1 failed copy of the data resulted in a partial merge on a separate drive. I now have a duplication of about 45% of the data with about 60% of that being in triplicate. the various sources of data also have additional files that are not in either other copy due to how it was released and later realized to be incomplete.Some of the files exist in both locations but even though the size states 3mb for both 1 of the files may only have 2mb of data inside the file due to a failure to copy. These files are on a Linux system.
I need a way to rebuild the file structure so that there are no duplicates and the latest file is able to be presented in the final dataset.  on the new server I would like the /storage folder structure to be rebuilt with every file.  /restore/storage to be populated with every folder and receive 3 types of files. 1)filename.history which would list for example readme.txt was found in /a/b/c/ and a/b/f the non duplicate files are stored in /restore/storage/a/b/c/readme.txt/readme.txt.1 /restore/storage/a/b/c/readme.txt/readme.txt.2  or something of the like. and the restore folder would get the non identical content files with the same name with the ability to exclude things like programming extensions  x.h x.c etc.
2)filename.dup would be generated for every file that had a duplicate file by content or name and list where the files live.
3) a sub folder with the file name duplicates that would be merged that were from the same file structure.  ex  /a/storage/file1.txt /b/bad copy/storage/file1.txt and /c/bad merge/storage/file1.txt
Does any one know if there are utilities out there that could do some of that or if i would have to do it manually by scripting and for example use rsync to move only non duplicate file names then get some sort of dif type script that would scan the origin folders contents and verify if the 2 files are identical and delete if so.  if the checksum is different keep it in the starting location to be reviewed and stored appropriately or deleted if matching the contents of the previously moved file?
